# How to forward traffic from a Remote Desktop to my local machine?

Tags: remote-desktop, putty, remote, debug

I have a web application running on 192.168.48.16:8081 and want remote debug it from my local machine. I can connect to the 192.168.48.16 via Remote Desktop. How can I forward all the traffic on 192.168.48.16:8081 to my local machine on port 6789?

Comment: The Visual Studio debugger supports remote debugging. Maybe you should pursue attaching a local debugger to the remote program. GDB also supports it, but it is usually easier to work with Microsoft tools.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and can't change that for several reason.